# react media query does not change grid columns

Tags: reactjs, media-queries

This is my first time using media queries in react and I would like to display all my elements in one column instead of 2 if `max-width:600px`

My code :

```js
import '../App.css';

<div className="results">
  {loading ? (
    <p>Loading</p>
  ) : (
    //this is the style of my <ul> with 2 columns
    <ul className="recipe-list" style={{ listStyle: 'none', display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr' }}>
      {recipes.map((r, index) => (
        <li style={{ margin: '120px' }} key={index}>
          <Recipe pic={r.recipe.image} ingredients={r.recipe.ingredientLines} meal={r.recipe.label} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )}
</div>;
```

App.css

```css
@media only screen  and (max-width : 600px) {
  //does not work !
 .recipe-list{
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
 }
}
```

I think that my style does not change since I have set grid template columns inside my element but I am not sure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul className="recipe-list" style={{ listStyle: 'none', display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr' }}>
```

try to move `style` to `app.css` as well. i think the inline css has higher priority.